# Drupal Import Commerce Product Display Multiple Images With Feed?

Tags: feeds, commerce

So... I have been attempting to import a list of products from a D6 site into Commerce Kickstart 2.6 and at every turn it's fraught.

My latest attempt has been to
a) Use Node Export to get a CSV of products from old site. Good.

b) Import using Commerce Product Feeds, first to get the Product and then again to get the Display (nodes). Three problems:

How does one map the 'images' field in the CSV? The CSV I'm importing has a path to the JPG file for each product in the folder where the images can be found. Eg.

```
  /sites/default/products/myproduct.jpg
```

Two issues:

1. This works for -one- image, but not if the product has multiple images. I tried mapping the CSV columns for each image path to the 'Images' field in the importer multiple times but this did not work. Again, only the 1st image imported
2. I can't figure out how to add the ALT tag to each product.

So: should each image be simple strings or is there some other data format (eg. array)?

Comment: Search for video tutorials by Randy Fay from commerce guys on the subject. You will also need [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) module.

Comment: Please see update. I've figured out -most- of it BUT I cannot get the images to import. They only appear on the importer for the -Product- when it seems to me they should appear on the importer for the -Node- (ie. the 'Display'). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When using Feeds & Commerce Product Processor you might want to to install Feeds Tamper as well. If the field that you are importing has multiple values you will typically have a delimiter (comma). I'd suggest using the explode function from Tamper to break the field into an array of values to import.  It might also help if you do a replace on the values you exploded to use the public file URI syntax (public://products/myproduct.jpg).